# How to retrieve data by dates that are not affiliated with the same field in each record

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a data base that has fields (i.e. Date 1, Date 2, Date 3, etc.).  Associated with those dates are Breakfast 1, Lunch 1, Dinner 1.  Each person's Date 1 is not necessarily the same date depending on when they are ordering their meals.  I would like to be able to pull how many breakfasts, lunches, and dinners are associated with a particular date (i.e. How many breakfasts are there for May 4, 2013, etc. which may be one person's Date 1 and another person's Date 2.  PLEASE HELP!  I am completing stuck with how to pull out the information I need in the format that I need able to sort by date.  I have put together a beautiful form to add data, but it has become quite the challenge to retrieve the data.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer. Depending on how you tables are organised (not in the OP) and what primary and foreign keys are used  it could be a simple select count where date is.

Comment: So, when I created my table to input data, I had to have a date field associated with each day of the week; therefore, I labeled them Date1, Date2, Date3, etc. In the record, I have info such as Name, Address, Phone number along with the meals they ordered (i.e. Breakfast1 is associated with Date1 for inputting purposes).Therefore each record could have a different date input into the Date1 or Date2 field depending on how many days they ordered meals.I need to find out how many Breakfasts,etc. were ordered on a particular date (ie.05/04/2013) which may be in Date1 or Date2 field.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your comment it sounds like you have a table something like this:

[image: data]

And you want to have a query to find all of the breakfasts by date. The problem is the data is not form that is easy for SQL to query. You need to put it a more relation format for database to be able to query it (this process is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

You need the Date to be a single column something like this:

[image: normal]

Then you can run queries with a `GROUP BY` clause to group and count all of the breakfasts by date.

Comment: It is more like this.  If I did it the way you suggest, I would have to input each customer multiple time.

Comment: Date 1 Breakfast 1 Lunch 1 SL 1 Dinner 1 Date 2 Breakfast 2 Lunch 2
4/21/2013 2   2   
4/20/2013 2      
4/19/2013    4 4/20/2013 4 4
4/20/2013    2 4/21/2013 2 
4/21/2013    2 4/22/2013 2 
4/26/2013    1 4/27/2013 1 
4/26/2013    1 4/27/2013 1 1
4/26/2013    1 4/27/2013 1 1
4/26/2013    1 4/27/2013 1 1
4/29/2013    1 4/30/2013 1 
4/29/2013    1 4/30/2013 1 
4/29/2013    1 4/30/2013 1 
5/3/2013    1 5/4/2013 1

Comment: Sorry, it didn't paste like I wanted it too :(

Comment: Brad, Is it ok if I send you the form I compiled for you to take a look at and make suggestion?

Comment: Travelling today. Could look at tomorrow.

Comment: That's fine.  Can you give me your e-mail address?